# How does entropy increase when measuring something?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information, poincare-recurrence

If I have a gas that starts in a corner of a box it will have low entropy. I have a detector on the corner that measures "1" if all the particles are at the corner and "0" otherwise. If I let the system evolve (starting at the corner) its entropy will increase (proportional to $1/V^n$), but in one of the Poincaré recurrences the detector will measure "1" and the entropy of the gas will decrease (again).

I know this is an open system (box + detector) but I don't see why just having 0 or 1 will make up for the big loss of entropy of the gas. Is it in the time it outputs 0 and 1 (it will output 0 for a long time and 1 a brief amount of time)? And if so, how can you quantify the entropy increase of this detector? (and finally being able to see that the second law of thermodynamics still holds).